# Pull one value from multiple rows in column

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building an advanced report to pull data from wordpress/woocommerce. Most data is in a `meta_value` column with a `meta_key` to link with.

I want to pull the `meta_value` where `meta_key` is equal to a few key values, such as `_price` or `_stock`. I can write the below formula to pull one specific item from that table, but I need about 10 different items and the ability to group by the values. We're not able to add additional groups by running totals.

```
if {wpyj_postmeta1.meta_key} = "_stock" then {wpyj_postmeta1.meta_value}
```

How can this be done without subreports?

Comment: Have you tried writing your formula with OR clauses? You know, IF {wpyj_postmeta1.meta_key} = "_stock" OR {wpyj_postmeta1.meta_key} = "_price" OR ... ... ... THEN {wpyj_postmeta1.meta_value}

Comment: yes but I need to be able to list these multiple fields  and be able to group by.  I'm looking for everything with  _stock (qty) >10 and have their price listed so we can calculate the qty X price and get total inventory value.

Comment: Would it be enough to group by meta_key and then by meta_value? Then the OR clause suggested by 4444 could be used just to suppress sections.

Comment: meta value is a longtext column so it won't allow group by.  Isn't there a way for a formula to print its results then i could suppress the value and keep the formulas

Comment: You can always inject a custom SQL Command into your report. Sounds to me like your needs are slightly outside the scope of Crystal, so I'd use it to transform the dataset as you like before it even reaches the report.

Comment: And people say RDBMS is passé.